# Flow record type by default

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type

Does anyone know which record type the flow is using by default when it creates the record?(without defining it) I cannot find any documentation about it.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: On the assumption you are using the Create Record element, this should simply use the configured default. Check the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.user_recordtype.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

Flows run in the context of the running user that initiated the transaction and as such are guided by the same record type defaulting rules as used elsewhere in the system.

This is typically configured in the running user's profile.  It can also be set in the User's [Preferences](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.user_recordtype.htm&type=5) It may of course be overridden by before save flows or before insert triggers.

That is, Flows are governed by the same record type defaulting rules used in the standard UX, or any API call, including Data Loader